# How can I sort an NSArray containing NSDictionaries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` which contains `NSDictionary` objects. Each of these `NSDictionary` objects contains an `ORDER` key.

How can I sort this `NSArray` based on this key within each of these `NSDictionaries`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example. Imagines you have an array of dictionnaries. Ecah dictionnary have 2 keys "name" & "dateOfBirth". You can sort your array by "name" like this :

```
//
// Sort array by name
//
NSSortDescriptor *Sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:Sorter]];
[Sorter release];
```

Note that `myArray` is a `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 4):

Read the [Sorting with Sort Descriptors](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/sortingFilteringArrays.html) section of Apple's [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html).

The example in this section covers sorting an array of dictionary objects by their keys.

Answer (score 1):

To Sort array of dictionaries
you have to use `NSSortDescriptor` by this you can sort array of dictionaries based on key

here in code, pass the `NSMutableArray` with dict Object by mean which you want to sort it

```
-(NSMutableArray*)sortingArrayOfDict:(NSMutableArray *)arrayTosort sortByObject:(NSString*)sortKey{
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:YES];
[arrayTosort sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
return arrayTosort;
 }
```

or even you can sort it in ascending or descending order by setting it YES/NO